# Will I utilize graphics hardware if I run X on the server?

Tags: x11, x-server

Will I utilize graphics hardware if I run X on the server?

If not, then what is it there for? E.g. [Dell PowerEdge R210 II](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-r210-2/pd) has  integrated [Matrox G200eW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrox_G200) with 8MB memory on board, and some of the latest Xeon CPUs have integrated Intel GPUs. How do these get used?

I will be using the server remotely, connecting to it over ssh and installing all the software from the command line. I plan to try [x2go](http://x2go.org), [Xpra](https://www.xpra.org/) and/or [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/). Will I utilize graphics card regardless? Seems counter-intuitive to me, as I will never need to display graphics on a locally attached monitor.

Answer (score 2):

**If you're running a X server**, you will utilize graphics hardware, as X needs at least some video memory to display anything. In the machines with integrated Intel GPUs, I think (from how it works on desktop systems) it will use some memory of the system.

But usually, you don't need to run X on a server except maybe for initial configuration. The graphics cards are there mostly for Windows (which needs a GUI for many tasks) servers.

This all does not apply if you have X only for giving remote clients access to GUI apps. The task of rendering/displaying stuff will be up to the clients. (In fact, I believe - though I haven't tried - you can install the X libraries without the X server)

Comment: "But usually, you don't need to run X on a server except maybe for initial configuration." Sure, I will only run X because I need to give remote users access to programs running on X. Added a paragraph clarifying that I only need to (or can, for that matter) connect to the server remotely over ssh. Does your answer still stand?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov now that you've clarified what you're doing, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general you need a graphics card for a console unless you plan setting up a console on a serial port or attempt console-less setup. E.g. in order to connect a monitor you need a graphics card and you'll need to connect a monitor for all PCs if you're going to setup the bios, ipmi, raid, etc...

So yes, anything that gets displayed on a monitor goes through a graphics card. And if you plan to run X then you'll use it. 8MB is not much: for 1024x768x24bit/32bit you need something like 3MB of graphics memory to store the contents of the screen and that's without using any hardware graphics acceleration.

Within Linux you'll also utilize it by the text console. Nowdays we also have KVM and modeset and with that you get much better text console speed and higher resolutions by utilizing the graphics card.

Comment: Added a paragraph clarifying that I only need to (or can, for that matter) connect to the server remotely over ssh. Does your answer still stand?

Comment: Depends on what you do. If you want to use the BIOS for example then yes. In all cases that you need a monitor, you need a graphics card (even an embedded one). Linux can work fine without a graphical console but PCs usually don't.